# Redirect ALL domain.co.il to www.domain.co.il (including sub folders)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know there is a lot of question regarding this though non of the answers is working for me .

My current .htaccess file ( which placed in the public_html folder ) is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.il/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Though this only redirects domain.co.il to www.domain.co.il .

If I try to enter a url like : domain.co.il/forums/forum.php it wont redirect to www.domain.co.il/forums/forum.php as i want it to do .

P.S of course the "domain" was replaced with my real domain name.

Comment: Does `/forum/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: yes, but i tried to remove it and see if it works but no luck.

Comment: Presence of .htaccess in subfolder is the only reason it won't work. Test changes after clearing browser cache every time and keep this rule as first rule in root .htaccess

Comment: OK, now i can see that this truly was the problem, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```